if tests seem to fail even though the variable echo works
I am trying to setup a script that will test for a user and if it doesn't exist I will add the user to a server. For now I am just testing to see if what I am testing for is found and I can do different actions based on what is returned. When I do echo "$BOBCHECK" after the ssh command I do get either found or missing results back as it runs through my server list so I know that part is working as expected and I have my variable set within the loop cycle. However the only result I get for the if tests is the failed test echo of "exist check failed" like the variable has been reset inside the if statements. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong here?
#!/bin/bash
#
#
for hn in $(cat /root/scripts/linux/linhosts.lst); do
  echo "" && echo "Checking for bob user on $hn" && BOBCHECK=$( ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "$hn" 'if getent passwd bob > /dev/null 2&>1; then echo "found"; else echo "missing"; fi' )
  echo "$BOBCHECK"
  if [ "$BOBCHECK" = "found" ]; then
    echo "exist check complete, user found"
  elif [ "$BOBCHECK" = "missing" ]; then
    echo "exist check complete, user not there"
  else
    echo "exist check failed"
  fi
done

Example output from the script running:

Checking for bob user on server42
Connection to server42 closed.
missing
exist check failed

Checking for bob user on server43
Connection to server43 closed.
missing
exist check failed

Checking for bob user on server44
Connection to server44 closed.
found
exist check failed

I have tried double brackets, double equals, nested if statements instead of elif statements, all with the same result. I even tried "-eq" which I quickly found only works for integers and not strings.

Are you trying to iterate over the lines i linhosts.lst, or shell-defined words? See Bash FAQ 001.

You can just use the exit status of ssh directly instead of trying to map it to a string. ssh ...; case $? of 0) echo "found" ;; 1) echo "not found" ;; esac.

@chepner Since hostnames should never contain whitespace, I don't think the warning is important in this case.

Make sure the script doesn't have CRLF line breaks. Fix it with dos2unix.

Instead of just echo "$BOBCHECK", try echo "$BOBCHECK" | xxd.

if ssh ....; then ... might be cleaner

I second @WilliamPursell's suggestion -- it's likely that $BOBCHECK contains something besides what's visible when you echo it. There might be spaces at the end, or maybe a carriage return character, or something like that. In any case, you should check with something like xxd that'll make normally-invisible characters visible. (But note that the echo will ass a newlike character to the end -- that's normal, and not a problem.)

All good advice above. I found it difficult to read the assignment to BOBCHECK=$(...). While &&ing those statements together is cute, it doesn't provide any useful error detection AND makes it difficult to read the meat of your whole process. Put that on its own separate line, please? (-;!? Otherwise, a good first question. (You can check for DOS line breaks (CR/LF) with cat -vet myProblemFile and if you see ^M$ at the end of each line, then run dos2unix myProblemFile. ... And change your editor to use Unix/Linux line-ending conventions, someplaces in the Settings ) Good luck.

It's not directly related to your surprising behavior, but a case statement would be a more natural fit to your script's behavior than is the if / elif / else you're now using.

I usually find the code clearest and simplest if you do as little processing as possible in the ssh session and then process the results locally, e.g. instead of BOBCHECK=$( ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "$hn" 'if getent passwd bob > /dev/null 2&>1; then echo "found"; else echo "missing"; fi' ) I'd do ent=$( ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "$hn" 'getent passwd bob' ) and then just test the exit status of ssh followed by testing the contents of ent if ssh exited with success.

Add printf '%q\n' "$BOBCHECK" to check for special characters.

If you use ssh with -t, it treats output as a terminal and expands \n to \r\n.
Consider (with bash printf):
$ printf '%q\n' "$(ssh -t user@host echo hmmm 2>/dev/null)"
$'hmmm\r'

To avoid this, don't use -t:
$ printf "%q\n' "$(ssh user@host echo ok)"
ok


Since getent probably doesn't ever exit with 255, and ssh exits with the exit status of the remote command executed, you could write:
#!/bin/bash
#
#
for hn in $(cat /root/scripts/linux/linhosts.lst); do
  echo "" && echo "Checking for bob user on $hn"
  ssh -t -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no "$hn" 'getent passwd bob >/dev/null 2&>1'
  case $? in
    255) echo "ssh failed" ;;
    0) echo "exist check complete, user found" ;;
    2) echo "exist check complete, user not there" ;;
    *) echo "exist check failed" ;;
  esac
done

